# .NET threaded command-line frontend

Tags: .net, multithreading, command-line, frontend

I want to capture the `STDOUT` from a command-line program such as `lame` or `gcc` and while it runs update the ui of a `winform`. The approach I tried fails because the stream/string is never updated. What correction are needed to make this approach feasible? Am I interpreting the use for `.WaitForExit()` wrongly?

```
Public Sub run(cmd As String, args As String, tgt As String)
    Dim out As IO.StreamReader = IO.StreamReader.Null
    Dim proc As New Diagnostics.Process()

    Dim thd As New Threading.Thread(Sub()
                                proc.StartInfo.FileName = cmd
                                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = args
                                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
                                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
                                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
                                proc.Start()
                                out = proc.StandardOutput
                                While Not proc.HasExited
                                    proc.WaitForExit(1)
                                    tgt &= out.ReadLine()
                                End While
                                ''debug
                                MsgBox(out.ReadToEnd)
    End Sub)
    thd.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: You are making an effort to append the output to the `tgt` variable.  Strange choice btw.  But then you don't actually use it.

Comment: I pass a reference to a textbox's Text property into the function

Comment: You still have a *lot* to learn.  Like what it means for a String to be *immutable*, the difference between ByVal and ByRef, why you can't update a TextBox from a worker thread.  You can't get that kind of help here.  Hit the books, write more code, leave this program on the shelf until you learn more.

Comment: I'veknown the difference between call by value and call by reference since 1999, but I'm only dimly aware how to do ui calls from worker threds in .NET. Anyway I could rewrite the program in a dozen ways to get the output where I want it, problem is this code is not delivering any output

Answer (score 0):

> What correction are needed to make this approach feasible?

Wait for the thread you have started to finish:

```
thd.Join()
```

and then you could use the `tgt` variable to update your UI.

Or even better, do this inside the thread, after your `While` loop. Just make sure that you are marshaling all calls to UI controls to the main thread using the [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method or you will get an exception telling you that you cannot manipulate any UI control from inside a different thread than the main one.

Comment: uh why would I need to use `.Join()`? And I want captur eoutput inside the loop, i.e. from time to time. What I get now is an empty stream.